# Unable to use the webview_flutter library in Flutter app [Android]

Tags: android, flutter, webview, android-webview

I want to use webview_flutter for my android application but unable to use it.
I have installed this package but it is unbale to detect in my project.
The version I have installed is `webview_flutter: ^4.4.2` .
I have tried both the widget name

```
WebViewWidget(controller: controller)
```

As well as

```
WebView()
```

But it is not detecting the package. Also i have manually imported the package in my project file but it is showing error. Please help me with this.

Comment: Try to write manually `import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';`.

Comment: I have also write it manually but not working

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer. Actually i tried running several libraries but it was also giving the same result. So I just ran

```
Flutter clean 
flutter pub cache repair
```

And then restarted my laptop and it works. I Guess the issue is with the .gradle file.